# Duda para validación de ofertas con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validación

mi duda es la siguiente, estoy haciendo un curso de Udemy que se llama "Haz ingresos pasivos con PHP y APIS de programa de afiliados", y mi duda es que en el curso se hace el siguiente código

```
/*=============================================
VALIDAR OFERTAS
=============================================*/

var valorDescuento = $(".valorDescuento");
var precioFinal = $(".precioFinal span");
var precioReal = $(".precioReal small");


var precioRealArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < precioReal.length; i++) {
   precioRealArray[i] = Number($(precioReal[i]).html().substr(1));
   console.log("precioRealArray", precioRealArray);

}
```

Y esto se muestra en la consola del curso:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo en el curso hace esto `precioRealArray[i] = Number($(precioReal[i]).html().substr(1));` para precios de $19.99 y entiendo que se hace para quitar el signo de "$", pero en su caso son dólares, y mi programa esta con moneda mexicana, es decir así: "MX$1,499"

Intente quitar los 3 primeros dígitos, es decir, colocar así mi línea de código: `precioRealArray[i] = Number($(precioReal[i]).html().substr(3));`, pero al momento de mostrarse en consola me sale "NaN", quise colocar en el .substr() 1,2 y 3 sin embargo me aparece de esta manera, espero me puedan auxiliar...
Estas capturas son de mi consola, y mi página

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar, ya que llevo semanas con este problema

Comment: El problema seguramente sea que tienes una coma en vez de un punto separando los precios. Prueba a cambiar la coma por puntos y a ver si funciona mejor :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en que `Number()` retorna `NaN` cuando el string que le pasas tiene una coma (`,`).
Puedes quitársela usando la función [.replace(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace) para quitar el símbolo antes de pasársela a `Number`. Intenta algo así:

```
/*=============================================
VALIDAR OFERTAS
=============================================*/

var valorDescuento = $(".valorDescuento");
var precioFinal = $(".precioFinal span");
var precioReal = $(".precioReal small");


var precioRealArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < precioReal.length; i++) {
   precioRealArray[i] = Number($(precioReal[i]).html().substr(3).replace(',','');
   console.log("precioRealArray", precioRealArray);

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido perfectamente! =)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una expresión regular para extraer números de una `string`, mira este ejemplo utilizando el formato de string que tienes:

```js
"MX$19.90".match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0]
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Españoil Lui, cuando proveas una respuesta por favor: cuida tu ortografía y agrega la documentación respectiva o en este caso una explicación de lo que estás haciendo. Con respecto a esta respuesta en específico toma en cuenta que las strings están con comas, por lo tanto siguen un formato `"MX$19.90"` y te recomiendo que uses los snippets para que los usuarios puedan reproducir tu código.